# How to get email notification in the Windows 8.1 lock screen and Start menu when using Outlook?

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, notifications, lock-screen

I'm using Outlook 2013 on Windows 8.1, and I'd like to get email notifications on the Windows lock screen and Start menu just like when using the Mail app; however, it looks like Outlook is unable to display that sort of notifications.

How can I get email notifications on the Windows 8.1 lock screen and Start menu when using Outlook?

Comment: Partial duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/867944/how-to-display-outlook-2013-notifications-on-windows-8-lock-screen, but while that question is full of case-specific details and issues, this is a more general question with a more general answer; also, the other question's answer is wrong (you don't need an IMAP account to access an Exchange mailbox in Mail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Modern (or Metro, as they used to be called) apps can display notifications on the Windows 8/8.1 lock screen and Start menu, and Outlook 2013 is not one of them; thus, it can't directly display those notifications.

As a workaround, you can configure in the Mail app the same email account you are using in Outlook: Mail will then display the proper notifications when messages arrive, even if you actually use another program (Outlook) to read them.

If you are using an Exchange mailbox, Mail has full Exchange support: just add your account to the app and it will autodiscover your server settings and sync your mailbox just like Outlook does. This will also sync your calendar and contacts, thus you will also get calendar notifications.

If you are using another mail server, you'll instead have to configure it in Mail as an IMAP account.